# mysql: unrecognized service ... but mysql is installed and it's working

Tags: mysql, ssh, command-line-interface, centos6, service

I'm trying to stop mysql and do some changes , then i'm going to start it again

I'm using a SSH client .

So i ran this 3 commends without any problem

```
mysql
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0; 
exit;
```

now when i type

```
service mysql stop
```

or

```
service mysql
```

i get

```
mysql: unrecognized service
```

whats wrong ? 
my site is online and it's using mysql database as i'm typing this , but i can't access

```
service mysql
```

some extra info

```
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
Server version: 5.5.31 MySQL Community Server
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its mysqld not mysql on Red Hat based distros.  Use `**service mysqld stop|start|restart**`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld stop
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

Or:

```
# service mysqld stop
# service mysqld start
# service mysqld restart
```

Comment: +1 This worked for CentOS.  I wonder how the service gets hosed, and "service mysqld start" isn't recognized?  When you call "/etc/init.d/mysqld start" once, they are found then.